# Change permalinks structure for specific category

Tags: permalinks

I need to change my permalink structure just for one category. Now I have: `/%postname%/` , but for News category I need this structure: `/%postname%-%post_id%/`.

**Question:** how to add %post_id% in specific category?

Answer (score 13):

This can be accomplished with some custom filters & actions.

Try placing this code in your theme's functions.php file:

```
add_filter( 'post_link', 'custom_permalink', 10, 3 );
function custom_permalink( $permalink, $post, $leavename ) {
    // Get the categories for the post
    $category = get_the_category($post->ID); 
    if (  !empty($category) && $category[0]->cat_name == "News" ) {
        $permalink = trailingslashit( home_url('/'. $post->post_name .'-'. $post->ID .'/' ) );
    }
    return $permalink;
}
add_action('generate_rewrite_rules', 'custom_rewrite_rules');
function custom_rewrite_rules( $wp_rewrite ) {
    // This rule will will match the post id in %postname%-%post_id% struture
    $new_rules['^([^/]*)-([0-9]+)/?'] = 'index.php?p=$matches[2]';
    $wp_rewrite->rules = $new_rules + $wp_rewrite->rules;
    return $wp_rewrite;
}
```

This will set up the permalink structure that you want for posts in the News category, and will also translate a request URI that looks like this:

```
/news-headline-text-01234
```

into this:

```
/index.php?p=1234
```

Source: This question was [already asked on wordpress.org](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/change-permalink-for-one-category-only) and my answer is based on the solution provided there.

**Edit:** Updated rewrite regex and rule to match the post id in a %postname%-%post_id% link structure.[2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27066173/2407742) The current code is tested and confirmed.

Comment: This gives me "Notice: Undefined variable: post_id"

Comment: Sorry about that.  I edited my post to fix multiple typos.

Comment: The link structure is perfect `/postname-149/`but gives a 404 when the link is clicked. Is something not being translated to `/index.php?p=1234` still?

Comment: Edited and tested with success. Good job dancriel

Comment: Thanks! I think I was using the wrong hook for the rewrite rules, my original version was meant to work with the 'rewrite_rules_array' action hook instead of 'generate_rewrite_rules'.

Comment: Also worth mentioning you need to update your permalinks by going to the permalinks page and clicking "save", in case anybody is missing that final step.

Comment: How would the code be altered to change the permalink structure for the news category from `/%postname%/` to `/news/%postname%/`?

Answer (score 1):

If you want it only for one category I think the easiest way is to use [wp_insert_post_data](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/wp_insert_post_data) or [save_post](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/save_post) to hook to the slug-generation of the post and simply add the `$post->ID` if the post has the category you look for.

This is the only solution I'm currently aware of, because AFAIK all the other core functions to manipulate the permalink structs can't be easily used only for one category.

[Here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/105926/rewriting-post-slug-before-post-save) is another question which has some more details on changing the slug on post update.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just add the post id then? If that's all you need? You could just do this with `query_vars`.

```
add_filter('query_vars', 'my_query_vars' );
```

You only need to check if you are in the 'special' category and if yes, add the var. Then utilizing the `pre_get_posts` hook, check if your post contains an ID and if yes change your query to get desired post.

Comment: I was looking for more detailed anwsers..