# Add category into post permalink

Tags: permalinks

what I want is if the category is "news" add /news-event/ before it.

Updated: its not working yet.

thanks to @jas I think this code will do it but I think I need to rewrite rule to make it works, Im not good at regex so I can not know how to do it, this is what I have tried so far.

```
  add_filter( 'post_link', 'custom_permalink', 10, 3 );
  function custom_permalink( $permalink, $post, $leavename ) {

// Get the categories for the post
 $category = get_the_category($post->ID);
 if (  !empty($category) && $category[0]->cat_name == "news" ) {
    $permalink = trailingslashit( home_url('news-events/' . $category. '/' . $post->post_name .'/' ) );
 }
return $permalink;
```

}

```
 function rewrite_rules( $wp_rewrite ) {
     $new_rules['news-events/^news/([^/]+)/?'] = 'index.php?name=$matches[1]'; //change 'test' to your category slug
     $wp_rewrite->rules = $new_rules + $wp_rewrite->rules;
    return $wp_rewrite;
 }
  add_action('generate_rewrite_rules', 'rewrite_rules');
```

my site has the structure permalink like this "site.com/en/postname1", I have post category "category1, category2,..."
I want to turn my post category into "site.com/en/category1/custom-text/postname1 or site.com/en/category2/custom-text/postname2". is it possible? Please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please go to **Settings > Permalinks**. Have a look at the [Permalinks](https://codex.wordpress.org/Using_Permalinks) page for other possibilities.

For You I think you need to use:

```
/%category%/%postname%
```

Hope this help!

**UPDATE :**

For additional slug based on category :

```
add_filter( 'post_link', 'custom_permalink', 10, 3 );
function custom_permalink( $permalink, $post, $leavename ) {

    // Get the categories for the post
    $category = get_the_category($post->ID);
  if (  !empty($category) && $category[0]->cat_name == "news" ) {
        $permalink = trailingslashit( home_url('news/'. $post->post_name .'/' ) );
  }
    return $permalink;
}
```

Please adjust above code according to requirements for more details please follow [this answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/152306/change-permalinks-structure-for-specific-category) or [this page](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/change-permalink-for-one-category-only/)

Comment: Hi, thanks, it works but now I need to add one more custom slug like if category1 -> /news/category1/postname1 ---- category2 -> /artical/category2/postname2, is it possible?

Comment: I have added some code which will results your permalinks with additional slugs and please follow link to answer for detailed explanation ! Additional Link for similar solution and explanation, discussion https://wordpress.org/support/topic/change-permalink-for-one-category-only/

Comment: No Problem and happy to hear its working for you :)