# URL rewriting: removing the site's basename for a specific category

Tags: permalinks, url-rewriting, urls, htaccess

I have a prestashop site with a WP blog inside.
I'd like to use Wordpress for some contents of the site but do not wish to show it as a content of the blog, so I'd like to remove the WP folder name from the URL. 
The general permalink structure of WP is :

```
mywebsite.tld/myblog/%category%/%postname%-%post_id%/
```

I want to skip `/myblog/` if the category name is **OutOfBlog** so that it becomes

```
mywebsite.tld/subcategoryname/(+postname)
```

instead of

```
mywebsite.tld/myblog/OutOfBlog/subcategoryname/(+postname)
```

Using `.htaccess` in the site root, I've managed this rewriting, but it seems that once redirected to myblog, it ends up with `myblog/OutOfBlog`

Do I have to remove RewriteBase **/myblog/** in my `.htaccess` in WP folder?
Or/and should I add a function using rewrite API in my theme's `function.php`?

I saw this topic [Change permalinks structure for specific category](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/152306/change-permalinks-structure-for-specific-category)
but I don't know how to change the home URL.

Could someone help?