# Can I override the permalink/slug on creation

Tags: custom-post-types, plugin-development, permalinks, slug, wp-update-post

I have a plugin that imports data from an external API, creates a 'Product' Custom Post type ( or updates an existing one ) and then adds all the meta data.

Every time we update the product from the external API, it rewrites the Permalink. We use the product's main name for the title, but want to add meta data to distinguish it from other products. For example. We have 3 Products called 'Vitamin C' but they're different strengths and flavors ( say, orange, berry and lime )

I have two questions:

1. What WP method triggers the permalink update?
2. How do I prevent it?  `add_action`? `add_filter`?

I would like to do two things:

1. Choose a custom pattern for the permalink. ( Post Title + Strength + Flavor )
2. NOT override this when updating the product ( so custom changes are not overwritten )

The plugin that imports the product is in a class and here's the methodwhere i think the change is happening :

```
/**
 * Update the title and content of Product post.
 *
 * @param int $id
 */
private function update_product_post( $id ){
    $title = $this->current_product->PrimaryName;
    $content = $this->current_product->PreviewSummary;

    $post = array(
        'ID'            => $id,
        'post_title'    => $title,
        'post_content'  => $content,
        'post_name'     => $title,
    );

    wp_update_post( $post );
}
```

There's lots of other code after this method is called that uses the `update_post_meta` as well. I don't think updating meta would trigger a permalink change but here's one example.

```
/**
 * Update a single primary meta field for a product.
 *
 * @param int $post_id
 * @param int $pim_id
 * @param string $field
 * @param string $lang
 */
public function update_primary_meta( $post_id, $pim_id, $field, $lang){
    $primary_meta_fields = $this->plugin_meta->get_primary_meta();

    // check to make sure meta key is valid and product exists in API.
    if ( ! array_key_exists( $field, $primary_meta_fields ) || ! $this->get_product( $pim_id, $lang ) ) {
        return;
    }

    $value = $this->get_product_property( $field );
    if ( $value ) {
        $meta_key = $this->prefix . $field;
        update_post_meta( $post_id, $meta_key, $value );
    }

}
```

I have slightly modified the code here: [Change slug on post creation](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/217075/change-slug-on-post-creation) to affect the `product` custom post type and have removed most of the code and appended `FOO` to see if it would work, but it doesn't seem to trigger. I'm not sure if it's the way I'm calling it from a plug-in or not.

Anyway, if anyone can help me understand where to look first for where permalinks are set and how to override them or provide me with some sample code or at least put in the right direction, it would be GREATLY appreciated.

A blog post about how to dynamically override these things would be even better!

Comment: I presume you use `update_product_post()` for updating the product. `'post_name'     => $title` this is actually your post slug. So if there is any change with the name of the product (extra word for example) you will be overwriting the slug. [Codex - Class WP_Post](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Post#Member_Variables_of_WP_Post).

Comment: Oh my.... why didn't I see that? It's staring at me right in the face. I'm off to do some tests.