# Modify post slug before saving

Tags: permalinks, hooks, slug

I would like to modify the slug of new posts by adding text before and after the original slug. The slug is then sent over an API via a plugin that hooks into `save_posts` and `transition_post_status`.

```
add_action( 'save_post', array( $this, 'action_save_post' ), 11 );
add_action( 'transition_post_status', array( $this, 'action_transition_post_status' ), 9, 3 );
```

I was originally using a method as indicated [here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/217075/change-slug-on-post-creation/217101#217101) which uses `save_post`, however while this method did correctly change the post slug on the website, the old slug still got sent over the API.

In the method linked to above, I tried changing the `save_post` hook priority to `6` from `10`, however that still didn't work.

I then tried something totally new, which was this:

```
function custom_permalink_slug( $original_slug, $slug, $post_id, $post_status, $post_type, $post_parent ) {
    $support_post_type = array( 'deal' );
    if ( in_array( $post_type, $support_post_type ) ) {
        $rand = '';
        $rands = get_the_terms($post_id, 'rand');
        if (!empty($rands) && !is_wp_error($rands)) {
            $rand = $rands[0]; // Only get first rand if there is more than one
            $rand = sanitize_title( $rand->name );
        }
        if (empty( $rand ) || strpos(  $original_slug, $rand ) !== false) {
            return; // No subtitle or already in slug
        }
        $slug = $rand . '-' . $slug . '-home';
    }
    return $slug;
}
add_filter( 'pre_wp_unique_post_slug', 'custom_permalink_slug', 100, 6 );
```

This method seems like it changes the slug correctly, as it displays the new slug on the post edit screen, however in reality it is still using the old slug (presumably because it doesn't change the `post_name` meta field).

Any ideas how to get this working correctly?

Comment: Have you tried with the [`wp_after_insert_post`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/wp_after_insert_post/) hook instead of `save_post`? What's the code in your `action_transition_post_status()` function?

Comment: @SallyCJ I tried changing `save_post` to `wp_after_insert_post` in the plugin code, however that didn't help. Here is a link to the plugin code: https://github.com/aaroneaton/better-yourls/blob/93975caea25d76c47f6e2b4068ba49ff4636970c/includes/class-better-yourls-actions.php#L45

Comment: So you want to change the `post_name` (post slug) and then you tried using the `save_post` hook, but when you make your remote API call, you're still getting the old post slug, i.e. the one before you added the "before" and "after" text? If so, then why not update the slug and make the API call via the same callback? I.e. Store the slug in a variable, pass it to `wp_update_post()`, and use that variable with your API request.

Comment: Thanks for your reply @SallyCJ. I would rather a method that wouldn't require me to edit the actual API plugin's files. Do you think that is possible in this instance?

Comment: Actually, I couldn't find any instance of `post_name` in the [code](https://github.com/aaroneaton/better-yourls/blob/93975caea25d76c47f6e2b4068ba49ff4636970c/includes/class-better-yourls-actions.php) you linked to, and looking at line 419, is that what you meant by, "*The slug is then sent over an API via a plugin*"? Or did you mean line 404 which retrieves the *permalink* which uses the post slug?

Comment: Do you want to change the slug only when the post is created or also when it gets updated?

Comment: Sorry if I was confusing. [Here is the code](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/217075/change-slug-on-post-creation/217101#217101) that changes the post slug, and uses `post_name`. Then, the plugin I linked to sends over the slug via an API whenever the post is saved or status changes:  [Line 45 and 47](https://github.com/aaroneaton/better-yourls/blob/93975caea25d76c47f6e2b4068ba49ff4636970c/includes/class-better-yourls-actions.php#L45).  As for your second comment, yes I would also like to change the slug when updated.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to reply to your message in the (now-frozen) chat discussion.. and I've also deleted my answer. Nonetheless, I still wanted to know if you've solved the issue? If yes, what's your solution?

Comment: @SallyCJ No problem, and I appreciate you following up! As of now, I am temporarily using your previous solution even though it is creating duplicate links in Yourls. I will either have to rewrite the API (not sure where to start with that) or move to another link shortener.