# Is there a way to add a ACF/metadata field data to a custom post type permalink?

Tags: url-rewriting, advanced-custom-fields

I am confused around how the `add_rewrite_rule` function works, especially with custom post types.

I have a custom post type `books` and for each post, I have a ACF field that is called `ISBN`. Right now, my permalink structure is:

`/books/%post-title%/`

But I would like for it to be:

`/books/%isbn%/%post-title%/`

I had originally attempted this:

```
function wpd_test_cpt() {

    add_rewrite_tag( '%isbn%', '([0-9]+)' , 'isbn=' );
    add_rewrite_rule(
        'books/([0-9]+)/([^/]+)/?$',
        'index.php?post_type=books&isbn=$matches[1]&name=$matches[2]',
        'top'
    );

}
add_action( 'init', 'wpd_test_cpt' );

 function wpd_test_post_type_link( $permalink, $post ) {

    if ( 'books' === $post->post_type ) {
        if( $isbn = get_field( 'isbn', $post->ID ) ) {
            $permalink = str_replace( ['%isbn%'], [$isbn], $permalink );
        }
    }

    return $permalink;
}
add_filter( 'post_type_link', 'wpd_test_post_type_link', 10, 2 );
```

And then tried to flush the rewrite rules, but it did not change anything on my site.

How can I grab the `ISBN` value from the postmeta and add it to the permalink for each of the custom post type posts?

Comment: I think you need to declare arguments in slug when creating the CPT

Comment: This may be a repeat of this question?  https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/217075/change-slug-on-post-creation/217101#217101

Comment: @mysticalghoul was right, so have you already tried doing that? Also, a side note - if you wanted to use the custom field for searching or filtering posts, e.g. to search for posts by a specific ISBN, then you should consider using a custom taxonomy instead, because [taxonomy queries](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/#taxonomy-parameters) are better (than [meta queries](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/#custom-field-post-meta-parameters)) for such purposes.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, for what you are trying to do, you do not need to manually add a new rewrite tag or rule.

If you want to change the permalink structure of a custom post type, then use the [`rewrite` parameter for `register_post_type()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/register_post_type/#parameter-detail-information) and set the **rewrite *slug*** to your preferred permalink structure, like so:

```php
$args = array(
    'label'   => 'Books',
    'public'  => true,
    'rewrite' => array(
        // This means that the permalink URL would be
        // https://example.com/books/<ISBN>/<post slug>
        'slug' => 'books/%isbn%',
    ),
    // Your other args.
);

register_post_type( 'books', $args );
```

Then use the [`post_type_link` hook](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/post_type_link/) to replace the `%isbn%` in the permalink with the correct value.

So looking at your code, you do not need this part: `add_action( 'init', 'wpd_test_cpt' );`, but you do need this: `add_filter( 'post_type_link', 'wpd_test_post_type_link', 10, 2 );`.

<sub>PS: Don't forget to flush the rewrite rules after removing the unnecessary part above and changing the CPT's rewrite slug.</sub>